# Any obfuscator which is working for Nodejs Express source code

Tags: node.js, docker, express, obfuscation

I read many tools or libraries that can obfuscate Javascript source code (single file mostly in the example). Here is my question, can these obfuscators work for Nodejs Express.js whole project source codes including node_modules? I couldn't really find an example or a matched answer that does for Nodejs Express.js project and I doubt...

Edit: My intention is to protect source codes reading from client side. Because the source code will be built into docker image and push to DockerHub. Then, the clients will download them and spin a docker container inside their clients.

Comment: Same here. Found any solution?

Answer (score 5):

use [**pkg**](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) or [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) module to compile it to binary if you are looking for source code protection.

Obfuscation can easily be reverse-engineered.

OR

Write the business-critical logic using **N-API** in C/C++ to get compiled node modules.

OR

A paid solution https://jscrambler.com/

If you are interested in Obfuscation,

Refer https://obfuscator.io/ (javascript-obfuscator) , UglifyJS, etc.

Also

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-compile-node-js-code-using-bytenode-11dcba856fa9

Comment: Simply I wanted to protect source codes reading from client side. Because client will download the docker image from dockerhub and spin a docker container inside their clients.